# Converted Video doesn't play on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, h.264, mp4

I'm trying to embed video playback on a website, using HTML5 video tags.

For some example mp4 files I found, the video plays well on both IE9 & Chrome,
but when I use mp4 files converted from avi/mkv files I have - The video plays only on Chrome, while IE9 refuses to play it.

I've tried several video conversion tools:
HandBrake, Miro Video Converter, Freemake Video Converter.
All produced mp4 containing H. 264 video & AAC audio - And all works well on Chrone.

I also tried playing around with IE9 multimedia/security options - but nothing has changed.

Well, I read about IE9 having a bad support for video playback and html5 in general, but still - it's clearly stated that mp4 is supported for all h264 profiles.

As you can understand - I have a priority for this website to work well on IE9 - So I'd appreciate any tips here.

Comment: Could you share a link to a video that places and one that doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and found out that it's the combination of `Miro Video Converter`, `videojs` and `IE9`:

When I convert with `EasyHTML5video` and standard settings (you cannot change any setting) everything ik OK and plays is `IE9` with `videojs`.

When I convert with `Miro Video Converter` and standard settings (you cannot change any setting) `IE9` doesn't play and has a `VIDEO OBJECT` error.

I've compared the 2 outputs and I think it's only the audio that is different. `Miro` is 2 channel `48Khz` and `EasyHTML5` 1 channel with `16Khz`.

I hope to find the right conversion tool, `Miro` is better quality than `EasyHTML5video`, but maybe there is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be using a plugin which utilizes feature detection such as VideoJS

It will provide the necessary fallback to flash if the video will not display correctly on the browser

Follow the instructions on http://videojs.com/ should be straightforward

Comment: Actually, I do use VideoJS, and no flash fallback happens. It seems that IE9 "knows" it supports the video/mp4 mime-type so it tries to play the video but can't decode it or something.